# Parse SQL Statement and reconstructing after modifications using java

Tags: java, where-clause

Does anyone know how to parse SQL statements, and again build in back using Java? This is required because I would need to add extra columns to WHERE clause based on the some conditions. FOr example, based on the Logon user, I would need to decide whether the user is restricted to see the records like it is restricted outside USA.

Comment: [JSqlParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) can be used for this

Comment: Yes you can just create a query string and use if statement where needed your extra coulm add ... After that execute this query .

Comment: SQL is entered dynamically by the business user in UI. Before it is executed, I need to intercept and rebuild if needed to apply security restriction(s). Having said that I cannot have condition_2=? and add or remove it in Java layer.

Comment: is JSqlParser open source and does not require any license? Any Code example will help.

Answer (score 2):

use jsqlparser
examples:

```
CCJSqlParserManager ccjSqlParserManager = new CCJSqlParserManager();
    Select statement = (Select) ccjSqlParserManager.parse(new FileReader(path));
    PlainSelect plainSelect = (PlainSelect) statement.getSelectBody();
    Expression expression = plainSelect.getWhere();
```

Answer (score -1):

See below example

```
    String sqlstr= "select * from [table name]  where [ column 1]='value' or ? "
    If( your condition){
    sqlstr= sqlstr+" [ column 2]=' value 2'";
    }
// Now write your execution statement
```